# How to set "e" in RSA structure?

Tags: openssl, rsa

Recently i upgraded openssl from 1.0.2 to 1.1.0. As RSA structure is opaque in new opnessl i made some modifications in my code as follows :

**Old Code**

```
RSA *rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(PKEY);
if(NULL != rsa)
if(!BN_set_word(rsa->e, 65537) || !EVP_set1_RSA(Pkey, rsa))
```

**New Code**

```
RSA *rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(PKEY);
BIGNUM *e_new=BN_new();
if(NULL != rsa)
if(!BN_set_word(e_new, 65537) || !EVP_set1_RSA(Pkey, rsa))
```

But Now "e" variable is not set in 'rsa', So how to set "e" inside rsa? Pls suggest me corresponding API

Comment: Why would you want to overwrite the exponent value? `RSA_set0_key` might be what you want, though you will also need to copy the modulus.

Comment: HI, I need to set a new exponent value so am overwriting it. I used RSA_set0_key() and its working fine now. Thanks